# ASP.NET Razor Code - How to create begin-with logic true in conditional statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to create a logic like that returns true if values are begin-with or start-with some specific value.

For example -

I'm finding something similar to `==` `Equality` term that returns true if values are equal.

```
@{Year == 2014/April ? "True" : "False"}
```

The problem with this is `Month`. I want if `Year == 2014` then it returns true with any month.

How can I do this? Thanks!

**[Edited]**

My question is clear, I want anything come's after `2014` returns true.

Comment: is `2014/April` supposed to be a string you have?

Comment: your question is not clear at all, since you have provided code that would not compile.  is `Year` a variable you are trying to evaluate? and what is `2014/April`? where is that coming from? and if all you want is to compare `Year` (variable) to `2014` (string) then why would `April` be needed at all? and, `==` is equal, if you want after 2014 you want `>` maybe?

Comment: Mary, stating your question is clear does not make it clear. You need to provide explanations for what your variables are and clearly describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Indeed "equal to April 2014" is not even *slightly* the same as "anything that comes after 2014".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
@{Year == 2014 && Month == 4 ? "True" : "False"}
```

Comment: Thanks... Somewhat helpful

Comment: @MaryMelody: Well if you want more help than that, you'll need to be more specific in your question. I had to *guess* that you have a `Month` property available, as you hadn't provided much context.

Comment: It's only for simplified the question.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Almost solve my problem and I will do the rest... :)